# Multiple Text Views don't align properly in Linear Layout

Tags: android, layout, textview, alignment

I am trying to add 8 text views in my fairly simple layout.
I would like to have two text views per row and four such rows.
My challenge has been lining up the 2nd, 4th, 6th and 8th text views in this layout.
The text on the 1st, 3rd, 5th and 7th Text views are of different lengths.

I am not able to line up the seocnd text views in each row to be aligned vertically.

Basically, these text views need to start at the same line vertically aligned no matter what ever the length of the first text view in that row is:

can someone help?

Here is my XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/productDetailsLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<include
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/logo_logout" />


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ProductDetailsTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@color/Navy"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/ProductDetailsTitle"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ProductDetailsEditButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.36"
        android:text="Edit"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<include
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    layout="@layout/product_details_mainpage_part1" />

<include
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    layout="@layout/product_details_mainpage_part2" />

<include
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    layout="@layout/product_details_mainpage_part3" />

<include
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    layout="@layout/product_details_mainpage_part44" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help. You can play with the `background color`, and `top padding` of each `TextView` to make it the way you want it to be. Hope this helps.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout"
    android:background="#ffffffff"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/background"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ProductDetailsTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="50dp"
        android:text="Hello, I am tired" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ProductDetailsTitle2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="50dp"
        android:text="Hello" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ProductDetailsTitle3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="50dp"
        android:text="Hello" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ProductDetailsTitle4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="50dp"
        android:text="Hello" />
   </LinearLayout>


   <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/background2"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ProductDetailsTitle5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
        android:background="#ffffffff"
        android:paddingTop="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ProductDetailsTitle6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="50dp"
        android:text="Hello" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ProductDetailsTitle7"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="50dp"
        android:text="Hello" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ProductDetailsTitle8"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="50dp"
        android:text="Hello, something" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old post, but I have struggled with this as well. 
What I find is the most effective is to inflate the view, then set new linear layout params. This will cause two line and single line text views to align vertically center properly.

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    TextView textView = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.workout_summary_textview, null);
    inflater = null;

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
    params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

    textView.setLayoutParams(params);
```